Why it is hard to break a ice cube but it melts at room temperature?
recently i am trying to study the the behaviour of mater in different temperatures, so now i have came upon the problem that is at room temperature we can can change shape of water or we can break or  change it. but when we freeze this liquid then we cannot easily change its shape, i know that intermolecular force is very high between them but at room temperature it melts but when i force it with grater energy then it is not breaking or melting it is behave like a solid but at room temperature at very low energy it is melting.

Do you have the same problems with other solids? Ice isn't that special here save for the temperature range used.

Ice does not melt at room temperature.* It melts at 0C. If you take an ice cube out of the freezer, and you set it on your kitchen counter, then for as long as it actually is melting (i.e., for as long as some solid remains and its surface is wet) the temperature at the interface between liquid and solid will be 0C. [*Except, maybe under something like ten thousand times sea-level atmospheric pressure.]

Solids melt because at the melting temperature the average energy of the molecules forming the solid (in the case of you question the water molecules in the ice structure) is sufficiently high that their "motion" is enough to "escape" the intermolecular bonds (the molecules have enough energy to overcome the energy barrier needed to escape the potential well). When in a solid phase this motion is generally in the form of vibrational motion.
This "bond breaking" is well illustrated by the form of the Lennard-Jones potential which describes reasonably well non-ionic intermolecular interactions:
$V_{LJ}$ as a function of intermolecular distance $r$; @
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential" />
When reaching the melting temperature (from below) the average distance between the molecules approaches $r \approx 2$ in the graph, where $V_{LJ}\rightarrow 0$, i.e. it becomes extremely probable that a molecule in the solid will escape the negative $V_{LJ}$ region (as illustrated in the plot they have to overcome a kind of energy barrier for this, and this is why the solid structure is stable at temperatures below the melting point). At that point a phase transition starts to occur, because the molecules start escaping the potential well, to the point where after some time all have escaped and the solid becomes a liquid. (Strictly speaking it is enough to increase the variance of the distance distribution to have molecules escape the solid structure potential, and not necessarily mandatory to have the average actually reach the zero energy value). It is also interesting to note that at very very low absolute temperatures $T\rightarrow 0 \ K$ the distance between molecules tends to the minima of the potential at $r=r_m$ (I'm assuming in this discussion a monoatomic solid with equal (average) distance between all molecules, as is the case of ice).
Regarding your comparison of using "brute force" to break the crystal structure, there are a few points we must think about: by increasing the solid's temperature, the energy transfer is happening repeatedly, and that energy is being slowly distributed equally among the molecules. On the other hand, when you apply a force you are only directly affecting a very tiny portion of the molecules, the ones at the surface of the solid. They must be able to transfer it to other molecules for a phase transition to even be possible to occur. Generally in normal life situations, even if you are breaking a microscopic quantity of bonds with the force, a lot of the energy is being lost inelastically. A single application of a force, if it is not strong enough to immediately break the solid, might manage to make some molecules escape the potential well but it is generally a very small number of molecules compared with the total number of molecules in the sample (this again depends on the intensity of the force, the time interval in which it was applied, and the strength of the molecular bonds in the solid). If you repeatedly apply the force or apply it for a long enough time interval you will be able to easily melt (or most probably break) the solid. This is also true if you apply a force with strong enough intensity in a short time interval, but then the result is to break the solid and not melt it, because again the energy is not distributed evenly before the breaking occurs.

"On the other hand, when you apply a force you are only affecting a very tiny portion of the molecules[...]" That depends on how you apply the force. Hitting an ice cube with a hammer where the head is of similar size to the ice cube will definetely affect a significant amount of molecules, and hitting it hard/often enough will definetely melt the ice, probably a lot faster than just letting it sit in warm air (which only affects the surface, really).

Yes, you have a point, I will edit my answer. The point I was trying to convey was that the thermal energy distributes more evenly between the molecules than trying to apply a reasonably weak force a few times, but of course if you hit with a lot of force or repeatedly hit it you have a similar or even larger effect. Good point!
